# Retrieving werkzeug route variable args inside a before_request?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

If you have variable arguments in your routes, like the "bar" here:

```
@app.route('/foo/<bar>')
def foo(self, bar):
    return bar
```

How can you retrieve that in a before_request, like here:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    app.logger.info(???)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `request.view_args` to get the path variables.

Also， you can replace `@app.before_request` with `@app.url_value_preprocessor`, like:

```
@app.url_value_preprocessor
def br(endpoint, values):
    print request.path
    print values
```

Hence, you can get path variables from `values` and get url path from `request.path`.

Comment: The `url_value_preprocessor` decorator was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!